# No invariant complement?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory

How do I show that the representation $\rho: \mathbb{Z} \to \text{GL}_2(\mathbb{C})$ with $$\rho(1) = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$ has an invariant subspace with no invariant complement? This is probably showing equivalence to the fact that $\rho(1)$ is not diagonalizable, for starters...

Answer (score 2):

Hint: an invariant subspace of dimension $1$ must be spanned by an eigenvector...

Answer (score 1):

For every $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, $$\rho(n)=\begin{pmatrix}1&n\\0&1\end{pmatrix}.$$ Since $ \rho(n)(1,0)^\text{T} =(1,0)^\text{T}$, $E = \text{span}((1, 0)^\text{T})$ is an invariant subspace. Let $F = \text{span}((a,1)^\text{T})$ be any complement of $E$ and $n \neq 0$. We have $$\rho(n)(a, 1)^\text{T} = (a+n, 1)^\text{T} \not\in F.$$ So $F$ is not an invariant subspace. Of course, this is equivalent to the fact that $\rho(1)$ is not diagonalizable.